# Android Paypal Rest Api Payment Resource

Tags: android, paypal

Im trying to integrate Paypal in my android app. My payments are successfully done. But i want to verify my mobile payments. So i followed this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource) from Paypal. I am getting **paymentId and access Token** from Paypal.I double checked my client Id and secret is correct. I am getting error ***Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}*** My Code is:-

```
private void restApiCall(String access_token, String payId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        String payUrl = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/"
                + payId;

        String encodedTkn = URLEncoder.encode(access_token, "UTF-8");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(payUrl);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
        // header with the value of Bearer <>
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + encodedTkn);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        byte[] data1;
        data1 = new byte[256];
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int len = 0;
        while (-1 != (len = is.read(data1))) {
            buffer.append(new String(data1, 0, len));
        }
        Log.e("-----Pay Response", "" + buffer.toString());


        // Make the comparison case-insensitive.
        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your access_token coming from?  This error indicates the access_token is expired.

Comment: access_token is coming from this service https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#getToken